# Python opening and close file - not intuitive

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it me or to open or close a file in python uses different methods making it really not intuitive?
Is there a better way to do it?

example:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
try:
# do stuff with f
finally:
   f.close()
```

Now, why I use  the built-in "function" open but to close the file I don't have function "close" but I have to call the "object" method "close".

Comment: Think of `open` as a constructor (in Python 2.x, it was a near-synonym for the `file` type).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) keyword to make it a bit more intuitive. It will automatically close the file when you dedent. From the docs:

> The ‘with‘ statement clarifies code that previously would use try...finally blocks to ensure that clean-up code is executed.
>
> ...
>
> After this statement has executed, the file object in f will have been automatically closed, even if the for loop raised an exception part- way through the block.

An example:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # do stuff with f

# Do some other stuff - we dropped down a level of indentation, so the file is closed
```

More specifically, it will initially call the context's [`__enter__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) method - this does the initial file opening. Whatever is returned by `__enter__` is set using the `as` statement - in this case, the file returns `self` and it will be set to `f`. When the `with` block is done, it will call the context's [`__exit__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) method. For a file context, this does the normal `finally` block handling of closing the file.

Note that the `with` block won't handle exceptions for you, it just ensures `__exit__` is called (and that will gracefully closed the file) even if they do happen . So if you have a `ValueError` while working with the file you'll still need a `try...catch` block *inside* the `with` block to handle whatever that may do to your calculations/script/etc.

---

As Marcin noted, most languages do this in a `try...catch...finally` block. Java, for example, does this:

```java
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new File("file.txt"));
    // Read in data and do stuff
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Shouldn't be this generic, but you get the idea
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // Always executes
    if (reader != null) reader.close();
}
```

Comment: I'd add that the try/catch way is usual in most other languages which have exception handling.

Comment: @Marcin Something like the bit at the end now?

Answer (score 2):

This does the same:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # do stuff
```